# One computer cannot authenticate to TFS or Exchange

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, exchange-server, kerberos, ntlm

I have several computers... only one of which cannot authenticate to either my exchange or TFS server. (2 of the computers are at my home trying to connect to our exchange/tfs server at work, one of which as the problem).  Several other employees have not had any connectivity problems.

The errors I am seeing are

401 2 2148074254
 401 1 0
 401 1 2148074252

After about 2 days of hunting around, I am about ready to repave the computer and start from scratch.  As far as I can tell they are set the same.

I cannot connect to Exchange OWA using Firefox but not IE.  Same for TFS.
I have reset IE (using the tool at this URL:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737  -- if you have not seen it you should read the description, it is quite entertaining).  I have compared the trusted site settings between the one that works and the one that doesnt.  I have also compared the 'advanced' settings and can find no differences.  The credentials work perfectly from the 2nd computer, which eliminates any firewall related filtering problems.

I am at a total loss as to what else to try.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This question should be moved to ServerFault.com.  If you ask it there you will probably get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

"I cannot connect to Exchange OWA using Firefox but not IE"  does that mean you have it working for IE?  Are you sure "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" is checked for your client browser?